# SFMC API Triggered Journey: Random Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, split

If we add the random split in 2 paths in an API triggered journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, where contacts come one at a time after they sign up on a website, will this ensure that equal number of contacts are distributed in two paths?

If random split does not work, is there any way I could achieve this functionality? I want to test 2 paths in an API triggered journey: one path with email sent instantly and one path with email sent after waiting for a day.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this page: '[Split Journey Contacts at Random](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_split_journey_contacts_at_random.htm&type=5)'

> NOTE As each contact reaches the activity, the contact is assigned a path at random based on the distribution that you select. Each path is populated randomly, so its distribution of contacts often doesn’t match the configured percentage exactly. As contacts proceed through the activity, each path’s population gradually comes closer to its configured distribution percentage.

So this is a dice roll randomness as opposed to a gated split. So a coin flip has a 50/50 chance, but if you flip a coin 10 times you can have a 70/30 split. but if you flip the coin 1000 times you will be closed to a 50/50 split. The same holds true with a random split. If your population is large enough you split will be more accurate